# Join between two tables with two rows

Tags: sql, performance, join, between, self-join

I have two tables:

Table A:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 95 |
| XYZ | 85 |

Table B:

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| MaxVal | 90 |
| MinVal | 80 |

I want to achieve this result 85 is between 80 and 90 value, so we filter out only XYZ and not ABC :

| Result |
| --- |
| XYZ |

I'm trying as below:

```
SELECT Name as Result from TableA a, TableB b, TableB c 
where a.value < b.value and a.value > c.value 
and b.value=c.value and 1=1;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `b.value=c.value`, which is filtering out all records and select proper categories from tables `b` and `c`:

```
SELECT Name as Result from TableA a, TableB b, TableB c 
where a.value < b.value and b.category = 'MaxVal'
and a.value > c.value and c.category = 'MinVal';
```

Here's another option, in my opinion more readable:

```
SELECT Name as Result FROM TableA
 WHERE a.value > (SELECT value FROM TableB WHERE category = 'MinVal')
   AND a.value < (SELECT value FROM TableB WHERE category = 'MaxVal');
```